# How can i fix this css code ? and how & ~ works?

Tags: css

i have this css code . it is part of navigation drawer for website. i got from this website:

https://codepen.io/cassiocardoso/pen/fjqLp

but this code is not working and i checked it with css validator , it has error. And i dont understand how & ~ works!
can anyone help me what is its error and how can i fix it?

Thankyou very much

```
#mobile-menu-checkbox {
display: none;

&:checked {
  & ~ #mobile-menu-overlay {
     display: block;
  }

& ~ .mobile-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
}
}
```

Comment: but as i see in your example it works(with less)

Comment: Note that the CodePen mentions the syntax is LESS in the CSS pane, and it has a dropdown where you can choose to view the compiled CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `less` file your code works perfectly.

To use `css` use code as below(I convert it with [less to css](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/)):

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', Sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#mobile-menu-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
#mobile-menu-checkbox:checked ~ #mobile-menu-overlay {
  display: block;
}
#mobile-menu-checkbox:checked ~ .mobile-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
#mobile-menu-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
.mobile-menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 101;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #dcdcdc;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  padding: 10px;
}
.mobile-menu h1 {
  color: black;
}
#mobile-menu-btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
header {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
header .menu-link {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#items {
  line-height: 1.75;
}
```

```html
  <input type="checkbox" id="mobile-menu-checkbox">
  
  <nav role="navigation" class="mobile-menu">
    <h1>This is the menu</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <label for="mobile-menu-checkbox" id="mobile-menu-overlay"></label>
  
  <header>
    <label for="mobile-menu-checkbox" id="mobile-menu-btn">
      <span class="menu-link">Menu</span>
    </label>
  </header>
  
  <div id="content">
    <ul id="items">
      <li>Click in "MENU" to open the navigation.</li>
      <li>Mobile menu using just HTML + CSS.</li>
      <li>Uses Android's navigation drawer pattern.</li>
      <li>Lightweight and customizable.</li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Most probably You are using LESS syntax in normal css. These are inheritance operators specific to LESS.
Install less to css compiler in your project

Answer (score 2):

That code is a CSS high level subset AKA: **SCSS** using the LESS syntax (similar to SASS).

So it invalidates using regulas CSS validators. The code is interpreted and should be compiled into CSS using the right tools.
When converted to CSS it should translate to

```css
#mobile-menu-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

#mobile-menu-checkbox:checked ~ #mobile-menu-overlay {
  display: block;
}

#mobile-menu-checkbox:checked ~ .mobile-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

The `&` (followed by a selector) is a back-reference to the closest selector:

```
#someId {

    background: blue;

    &.red {                 /* same as #someId.red */
        background: red;
    }
}
```